# HTML Content DIV Frame over image not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been trying to make a simple DIV website based off of ONE Image, and it's just not working. I've aligned the buttons, in which the buttons do work, however the Content does not show over the content box area, what am I doing wrong?
The Content box's positioning is under #frame1 in the code. The javascript for the changeframe is located in the  tag.

```html
    <style>
    #video_panel_body,
    #video_panel,
    #imvuContent,
    #leftColumn {
        width: 1013px !important
    }
    
    #video_panel_header,
    #rightColumn {
        display: none
    }
    
    .box {
        overflow: auto;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #layout-container {
        font-size: 11px;
        font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
        width: 1013px;
        height: 1300px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    area,
    map {
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: 0
    }
    
    #layoutimg {
        position: absolute;
        width: 1013px;
        height: 1300px;
    }
    
    #content_container {
        display: none !important
    }
    
    #frame1 {
        margin-left: 292px;
        margin-top: 782px;
        width: 697px;
        height: 1058px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var btree = {
        _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
        decode: function (e) {
            var t = "";
            var n, r, i;
            var s, o, u, a;
            var f = 0;
            e = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
            while (f < e.length) {
                s = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
                o = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
                u = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
                a = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
                n = s << 2 | o >> 4;
                r = (o & 15) << 4 | u >> 2;
                i = (u & 3) << 6 | a;
                t = t + String.fromCharCode(n);
                if (u != 64) {
                    t = t + String.fromCharCode(r)
                }
                if (a != 64) {
                    t = t + String.fromCharCode(i)
                }
            }
            t = btree._utf8_decode(t);
            return t
        },
        _utf8_decode: function (e) {
            var t = "";
            var n = 0;
            var r = c1 = c2 = 0;
            while (n < e.length) {
                r = e.charCodeAt(n);
                if (r < 128) {
                    t += String.fromCharCode(r);
                    n++
                } else if (r > 191 && r < 224) {
                    c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
                    t += String.fromCharCode((r & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63);
                    n += 2
                } else {
                    c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
                    c3 = e.charCodeAt(n + 2);
                    t += String.fromCharCode((r & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3 & 63);
                    n += 3
                }
            }
            return t
        }
    };
    
    function changeframe(choice, id) {
        if ($("#layoutimg").attr("src") == btree.decode("aHR0cHM6Ly91c2VyaW1hZ2VzLWFrbS5pbXZ1LmNvbS91c2VyZGF0YS8wMi84OS83MC83OC91c2VycGljcy9TbmFwX2Jia3hTUVBucHk4OTcxMTY5OTgucG5n")) {
            $('#' + id).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                $('#' + id).html($('#' + choice).html());
                $('#' + id).fadeIn('fast');
            });
        }
    }
    </script>
    <div id="content_container">
       <div id="home"><br><br>HERE CONTENT FOR home </div>
       <div id="about"><br><br>HERE CONTENT FOR about </div>
       <div id="shop"><br><br>HERE CONTENT FOR shop </div>
       <div id="shout"><br><br>HERE CONTENT FOR shout </div>
       <div id="honor"><br><br>HERE CONTENT FOR honor </div>
    </div>
    <div id="layout-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7N610pv.png" width="1013" height="1300" border="0" usemap="#map" />
        <map name="map">
          <area shape="rect" coords="273,740,356,768" onclick="changeframe('home','frame1')">
          <area shape="rect" coords="360,740,445,768" onclick="changeframe('about','frame1')">
          <area shape="rect" coords="450,740,535,768" onclick="changeframe('shop','frame1')">
          <area shape="rect" coords="539,740,624,768" onclick="changeframe('shout','frame1')">
          <area shape="rect" coords="630,740,715,768" onclick="changeframe('honor','frame1')">
       </map>
        <div id="frame1" class="box"></div>
       <script>changeframe('home','frame1')</script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues with your code
this condition is falsy which why your tag is not replaced with the new html

```js
$("#layoutimg").attr("src") ==
btree.decode(
"aHR0cHM6Ly91c2VyaW1hZ2VzLWFrbS5pbXZ1LmNvbS91c2VyZGF0YS8wMi84OS83MC83OC91c2VycGljcy9TbmFwX2Jia3hTUVBucHk4OTcxMTY5OTgucG5n"
)
```

if you comment the above condition it will work but your css push it way down and text is white that's why you don't see it so something roughly like this should work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-volhard-7nt5d?file=/index.html
I made the text red so it is more visible for you to debug

Comment: Seemed to fix that issue, however now I have a new issue. I put the style, and the first script into their own seperate css/JS files and linked them, upon doing so it broke the script/style ???? But as soon as I put those back in the index.html instead of shortlinking them it works again.

Comment: Here is the modified version with css and JS as external files https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-volhard-7nt5d?file=/index.html

Comment: I figured out my issue. I was missing some of my #'s for the style.css Oops. Thank you so much!